# Sybase check if value is numeric

Tags: stored-procedures, sybase, isnumeric

How can I check if the value is numeric?
I tried is numeric but it is returning an error that the function is not found.

Example:

```
select *isnumeric*("abc") // returns 0 or false
select *isnumeric*("123") // returns 1 or true
```

Comment: Do you consider a value like "1.2E3" to be numeric?

Comment: isnumeric() is supported, but only in ASE version 15.0.1 or later.

Answer (score 5):

A reasonable method is to look for non-digits:

```
select (case when str like '%[^0-9]%' then 0 else 1 end)
```

This looks for strings of digits.  You can extend it to support negative signs, decimal points, and exponential representation if those are needed.